# Anaconda Python script does not use the right environment python

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, python-import

A package "example" has a script to `import example`. It is installed in a created environment on Anaconda on Windows but not on root environment.

After activating the environment, running directly from console I can import that package, but when trying to do the same from the script (`example.py --options`) the module is not found. `example.py` is located on `C:\Path\to\Anaconda\envs\test\Scripts`.

Checking `sys.executable` from the console I got `C:\Path\to\Anaconda\envs\test\python.exe` and from the script I got `C:\Path\to\Anaconda\python.exe` (from the root environment). 
I tried to associate .py files with the python from environment and setting %PATH% variable, but no luck working with these ideas.

PS: In the machine I use, I don't have admin access. No problems when working on Linux.